# jQuery.ajax() does not call success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Function not called after Ajax call. This servlet returns plain text and the result is shown in the browser when it is called:

http://ec2-23-20-139-221.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/heiper2/heiper?personid=205328&placeid=640161&timeid=1992-03

But if I call it within javascript using jQuery, something goes wrong. I first thought about a timeout, but a call takes ~10.000ms and I've set the timeout to 60.000.

Any ideas?

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://ec2-23-20-139-221.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/heiper2/heiper?personid=205328&placeid=640161&timeid=1992-03&callback=?",
  dataType: 'text',
  timeout: 60000,
  success: function(data){
  alert(data);
  }
});
```

The response header looks good too

```
Response Headers Δ7515ms
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1Date:Tue, 16 Oct 2012 18:22:51
GMTContent-Type:text/plain
Content-Length:1146
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a syntax error, you're missing a closing }

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://ec2-23-20-139-221.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/heiper2/heiper?personid=205328&placeid=640161&timeid=1992-03&callback=?",
  dataType: 'text',
  timeout: 60000,
  success: function(data){
      alert(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: sorry thats only a typo in the question, of course I've the closing }

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a close } but maybe you're getting an error status code (which should be in the response headers you posted.

Check your browsers console.

It might also be worth adding a handler for error. Example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://ec2-23-20-139-221.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/heiper2/heiper?personid=205328&placeid=640161&timeid=1992-03&callback=?",
  dataType: 'text',
  timeout: 60000,
  success: function(data){
      alert(data);
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('error'); // TODO DEBUG HERE
  }
});
```

Comment: ok error pops up. how to get any meaningful information within the error function? What could be a source of failure?

Comment: First thing I'd try is looking at the network response using something like fiddler or Chrome. See the 500 status code and hopefully a more meaningful error